# Getting building data at a coordinate

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I would like to be able to click on a building on a map and get the polygon that comprises the building at the clicked coordinate.

I looked into overpass api and tried the following:

```
<query type="way">
  <around lat="51.0566036" lon="13.7181033" radius="30"/>
  <has-kv k="building"/>
</query>
<union>
  <item/>
  <recurse type="down"/>
</union>
<print/>
```

If I choose a large `radius` I get too many buildings. If the `radius` is too small I don't get any buildings. Using `bbox-query` did not help.

I also tried `coord-query`, but I was not able to construct a meaningful query. The necessary query syntax seems to be different.

Is there a better approach at hand? Even withouth overpass, I have just to look into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you try to realize is a 'reverse geocoding'. To avoid the mentioned problems (AFAIK) usual implementations use an arbitary radius and then test the resulting shapes once more if they contain the desired position.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try the following: Testing with a small radius (50m) and if it fails using a large one (500m). After a few queries I'll reassess and see if I could optimise by using a different radius to find a good ratio between number of api calls to transfered data.

Answer (score 3):

A similar requirement was discussed in this [GitHub ticket](https://github.com/drolbr/Overpass-API/issues/86). At this time, Overpass API doesn't calculate area information for buildings, which would be required for `is_in`to work. However, you could set up your own Overpass API instance and adjust the area creation rules to also include buildings. For a small area this should be even feasible on your local machine.

Please also check all links in the GitHub ticket I mentioned. It includes a number of additional pointers which may be relevant to your problem.

Caveat: The performance and space implications of calculating areas for buildings on a world wide scale are unknown, respectively not fully tested yet.

Comment: Thanks for elucidating! At the start I don't want to set up my own instance. I've described what I'll do first in my comment to MaM's answer.

Answer (score 3):

There is a Python solution using gis_geometrics [1] and overpy. This Python program finds the building at LAT,LON. Put it in the same directory as gis_geometrics.py:

```
import overpy
from gis_geometrics import OSM_Polygon, Overpass

api = overpy.Overpass()
building = OSM_Polygon.getPolygonByCoords(api, LAT, LON)
if building is None: print("No building found.")
else: print(building.wayId)
```

With the way id you can make an overpass request to find the polygon coordinates.

[1] https://github.com/timojuez/home/blob/master/mylib/gis_geometrics.py